# Spring. Map field of @RequestBody with @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, mapping

Now I have code like this:

```
@RestController
public class ChildController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/parents/{parentId}/addChild", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public void addChild(@RequestBody ChildDTO child, @PathVariable Long parentId) {
    child.setParentId(parentId);
    //...
  }
}

class ChildDTO {

  private Long parentId;

  private String name;

  private double weight;

  private double height;

  //setters ang getters
}
```

Is there any way to map parentId in child object without calling setter in method body? 
I need it for my Aspect @Before logic

Comment: is this request mapping getting triggered from any javascript or UI. You could probably set this parentId from the caller of this requestmapping which is sending the requestbody

Comment: @mhasan frontend dev doesn't want to set parentId on js-side because AOP realisation is only my experiment. If I will not find solution without API changing, I will have to abandon this idea :(

Comment: I think this is not possible. Anyway, I would not recommend to do this. It's better if the client sends the id on the URL and in the RequestBody so you can verify in the server if the id on the URL match the ID in the RequestBody.

Comment: Is it not possible to set it in the client side ? Why should this happens dynamically in the BE ?